# Incremental percentage calculator for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, widget, calculator

I am in charge of a real estate agency website and we've just had a big change on stamp duty tax here in the UK. The website is built on Wordpress and I would love to be able to embed a calculator like the examples below on my homepage to attract visitors. How could I go about doing this?

I was thinking there would be a percentage calculator widget but that would just do a percentage of a single number, rather than working out the slightly more complex incremental percentage of stamp duty.

The way it works is the first £125k of your property is tax free. The value between £125k and £250k is taxed at 2%, the value from £250k to £925k is taxed at 5%, the value from £925k to £1.5mil taxed at 10% and anything above £1.5mil is taxed at 12%.

Examples:

- http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/autumn-statement/11271926/Stamp-duty-calculator-how-changes-affect-you.html
- https://www.moneyadviceservice.org.uk/en/tools/house-buying/stamp-duty-calculator

Comment: Where you want to put your calculator is important. You can develop this is as a plugin, as a widget or as a page. The way you should go to build this is Javascript, there's an example of a similar behavior here: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-calculator-script.phtml

Comment: I was thinking just on the homepage. I use Visual Composer to create the pages so I would just slap some HTML in a text widget or something I guess. My methods will probably make you cry - I'm new to all this coding lark.

Comment: Unfortunately for you there's no way to develop what you want with just HTML. You need a developer.

Comment: have you managed to solve it?